# How Testng creates object of test class and invoke methods of Test class?

Tags: testing, selenium, testng, appium

I want to know how test methods having @Test annotation are invoked. Does Testng create object of test class internally?  If yes then when does that object die? 
Here is my Testng file

```
 <test name="lOGIN" preserve-order="true">
<classes>
    <class name="xtr.chaut.test.LoginConnectHealthy">
        <methods>
        <include name="openLoginPage" />
        <include name="validLogin" />       
        </methods>
    </class>
            <class name="xtr.chaut.test.HomeTest">
        <methods>
        <include name="patientProfile" />       
        </methods>
    </class>
            <class name="xtr.chaut.test.LoginConnectHealthy">
        <methods>
        <include name="logout" />       
        </methods>
    </class>
```

here **LoginConnectHealthy** class appears twice. Does testng uses same object for them, or it creates different instance for them?

Comment: At this point, please mention what efforts you have made to answer your own question. For example, have you googled? Did you look at TestNG documentation? etc

Comment: i have searched it on google. but i didnt find anything. even testng document doesnt explain it

Comment: have you tried setting the verbosity to 10? if you do this TestNG tells you which tests it is/is not including and why.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: it is better to use a "AfterMethod" annotation than to instantiate a new class that calls "logout" separately.  TestNG is generally not designed to call the same class twice in a test group.  What it is designed for is 1 class each within a test group.  Just look at the doc for the `<packages>` tag and `preserve-order` attribute to see that is most likely the case.   It might coincidentally work but your milage will vary.

TestNG tests have a lifecyle just like JUnit tests have, with "Before" and "After" events.  If you look at the .html reports generated by a TestNG run, you will see these events spelled out in the report.   Therefore, there shouldn't be any question about the life of the test objects.   You might understand it better by just reading all the TestNG documentation, which includes information how Factories work as well as Data providers.  You could [poke around on this example I made](https://github.com/djangofan/testng-custom-report-example), run it with `mvn.bat test`, and then find the .html report file called methods.html .